# Can students in Hogwarts change their houses after official sorting has been done?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

People change as we know, as time passes, as they grow, as they face various situations in their life. Even wizards are basically people like muggles except for magic.

Say a student is intelligent so sorting hat puts him/her in Ravenclaw. But later on the student starts displaying bravery. This new trait starts overpowering his/her intelligence. So can the student switch to Gryffindor by himself, obviously after getting permissions and approvals of higher authority.

Basically, can students in Hogwarts change their house after official sorting has been done by sorting hat?

Comment: My question focuses on student's decision to change their own house. While the mentioned similar question asks whether it can automatically change, like Patronus changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no instance of such occurring in the books. while each house has it's desired traits, the sorting hat takes into account many factors including the personal wishes of the student. 
Herimone is one of Hogwarts smartest students and yet she is in Gryffindor because the hat took into account her other traits.

Comment: Hermoine is highly intelligent already before joining Hogwarts. She doesn't need to work on her intelligence any more. Thus, she is sorted in Gryffindor so that her other traits like Bravery is increased.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri Apparently the sorting hat is a Final Fantasy V fan.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: I don't follow FF, so didn't understand your comment :(

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri Well, in it you level up enough in a class and hit the peak, so you stop leveling in that one and start leveling in another one.  FFV was one of the first that made that a major gameplay element.  But many games do it, so maybe the sorting hat's a fan of some other RPG :)